# Display multiple models in a single view using partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, models, partialviews

I need to is display data from a two tables(Student and Grade) in a single view index.cshtml.

I have two partial views _StudentPartial & _GradePartial both strongly typed. I googled around and everyone says that I parent model should be used. So I created a parent model called MyViewModels below but I can't seem to get this to work. What's the correct way to do this?

My Model:

```
public class MyBigViewModels{
      public IEnumerable<Users.Models.Student> Student      { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<Users.Models.Grade>   Grade       { get; set; }
}
```

My View():

```
@model MyApp.Models.MyBigViewModels

// render content for Student 
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @Html.Partial("_StudentPartial", item)
}

// Render content for Grades
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @Html.Partial("_GradePartial", item)
}
```

My Partial Views

```
// _StudentPartial 
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Student>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
}


 // _GradePartial
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Grade>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.letterGrade)
}
```

Server Error in '/' Application

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MyApp.Models.Students]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Models.MyBigViewModels]'.

Answer (score 2):

in your outer view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

doesn't make sense.  Your model is not enumerable.  You want :

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Students)
{
   @Html.Partial("_StudentPartial", item)
}

// Render content for Grades
@foreach (var item in Model.Grades)
{
   @Html.Partial("_GradePartial", item)
}
```

and your partials would just take a single item:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Student

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
```

either that, or don't loop in your main page, and send the enumerables into your partials to loop.  Essentially you have 2 foreach's when you only need one.